# Routh-Hurwitz Stability Criterion

Tags: polynomials, roots, control-theory, stability-theory, linear-control

I started to an study introductory course in control theory. I understand that all the roots in the (system's) transfer function's denominator should be on the left hand side of the s plane in order to be stable. And I can use any math software such as Matlab to find all the roots of a polynomial and see if they are all negative. Easy. Then we learned about Routh's criterion to check stability. My question (or what I didn't understand) is: why to use such a (complicated) criterion, when (instead) I can use Matlab and directly find the roots of the polynomial? It is not much easier? I probably missed something deep...

Comment: I wonder this as well, however at my university Routh's criterion was only briefly mention. I myself find the Nyquist stability criterion much more useful, namely you can also apply it to experimentally obtained frequency response data, while in practice you never know the exact transfer function coefficients of a physical system, which are used in Routh's criterion.

Comment: What if there's a parameter (or several) in the transfer function, and you want to see for which values of this parameter the system is stable? With Matlab, you can only check the location of the roots for one specific value of the parameter at a time.